# How do I know if a class has a method in java and how do I invoke it

Tags: java, reflection

I need to know if a java class has the method

```
public double getValue()
```

if there is a method. I need  call the method.

Sorry, I forgot to say that this need to do at runtime

Comment: If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you can easily discover this.  Perhaps someone else can summarize the steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Class.getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get the `Method` object, and then [`Method.call()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to invoke the method.

`getMethod()` will throw [`NoSuchMethodException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html) if the class doesn't have a method with the requested name and signature.

Comment: Is parameter/return type validation necessary?

Comment: @Dave I would think so.  definitely safer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the class, and then the methods from the class.  Assume angst is your object.

```
Object angst = new Object();
Method[] methods= angst.getClass().getMethods();
for(i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
    if(methods[i].getName().equals("getValue") {
        //some boolean stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use [java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)